# Duplicate symbol linker error with LLVM compiler flag visibility=hidden

Tags: c++, boost, linker, static-libraries, llvm

I have a problem with a static library build with Xcode 4.6.2 using the LLVM Clang Compiler. The problem occurs only if I use the C/C++ Compiler flag visibility=hidden. The Linker reports me a duplicate symbol error. I will explain the setup in an easy scenario and I hope someone can explain why this happen.

Imagine I have two classes ClassA and ClassB which I compile into a static library myLib. As said above, I set the Compiler flag -fvisibility=hidden.
Then I have a project which creates an executable from a main.cpp which uses the myLib.

Here are the classes:

ClassA.h

```
#pragma once
#include <boost/exception/all.hpp>

struct my_error : virtual std::exception, virtual boost::exception {};

class ClassA
{
public:
  explicit ClassA() {};
  virtual ~ClassA() {};

  virtual void doSomething();
};
```

ClassA.cpp

```
#include "ClassA.h"

void ClassA::doSomething()
{
  BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION( my_error() << boost::errinfo_api_function("doSomething") );
}
```

ClassB.h

```
#pragma once
#include "ClassA.h"

class ClassB
{
public:
  explicit ClassB() {};
  virtual ~ClassB() {};

  virtual void doSomething();
};
```

ClassB.cpp

```
#include "ClassB.h"

void ClassB::doSomething()
{
  BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION( my_error() << boost::errinfo_api_function("doSomething") );
}
```

These two classes a build into my library without a problem. In my executable project which links the myLib I have the following main.cpp

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ClassA.h"
#include "ClassB.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

  ClassA A;
  ClassB B;

  return 0;
}
```

The C++ flags:

[image]

The build results in the following errors:

> duplicate symbol __ZTIPN5boost21errinfo_api_function_E in:
>       /Users/georg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ExceptionTest-dcnvciwqbwqvciaokkjjaqchftll/Build/Products/Debug/libExceptionLib.a(ClassA.o)
>       /Users/georg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ExceptionTest-dcnvciwqbwqvciaokkjjaqchftll/Build/Products/Debug/libExceptionLib.a(ClassB.o)
>   duplicate symbol __ZTSPN5boost21errinfo_api_function_E in:
>       /Users/georg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ExceptionTest-dcnvciwqbwqvciaokkjjaqchftll/Build/Products/Debug/libExceptionLib.a(ClassA.o)
>       /Users/georg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ExceptionTest-dcnvciwqbwqvciaokkjjaqchftll/Build/Products/Debug/libExceptionLib.a(ClassB.o)
>   ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture i386 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

If I change the Compiler Flags to the following it works:

[image]

The problem is the boost::errinfo_api_function object, but I do not understand why?

I hope someone can help me.

Kind Regards
Georg